# Get only the first match

Tags: regex

I would like to get the first match of the string only.

```
(?<=\[TITLE.+)suffix=[^|\]]+\|?
```

If my string is `[TITLE|suffix=my value|prefix=another value]`, it's all good and I get only 1 match but if the string is `[TITLE|suffix=my value|prefix=another value][DYNAMIC|suffix=my value|prefix=another value]`, I get 2 matches but what I need is only the first match.

See here: https://regexr.com/5h0t8

Comment: You can match the `|` after TITLE instead of the `.+` like `(?<=\[TITLE\|)suffix=[^|\]]+\|?`

Comment: @Thefourthbird I have tried this but then there is no match for the string `[TITLE|prefix=another value|suffix=my value]`

Comment: Then use `(?<=\[TITLE[^\]]*)suffix=[^|\]]+\|?` https://regex101.com/r/cRfGhN/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird perfect! Thank you!

Comment: @JvdV That also works :-)

Comment: `.+` matches *any* one or more chars other than line break chars. You just need to *temper* it with a negated character class that makes sure it does not overflow from one tag into another. As your tags start with `[` you may simply use `[^[]*` instead.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I think you may "finalize" the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the match more specific by excluding matching the characters `[` or `]` that denote the start and stop of the separate parts instead of using the dot to match any character.

You can choose to return the first match when you have more than one match, but you can make the pattern more precise to stay within the boundaries yielding a single match.

In this case, you can exclude matching `]` or as @[Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew)
 points out, exclude the opening `[`

```
(?<=\[TITLE[^\]]*)suffix=[^|\]]+\|?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cRfGhN/1)